# Can't access session variables outside submit button code

Tags: php, session-variables

I have a problem in accessing session variables outside the code for submit button.when i am printing the session variable within submit code it is printing but at the time of echoing outside submit code it is not printing the value of date .Actually i want to insert the value of session variable in database but it is not getting inserted .the code is given below:

```
  <!Doctype html>
  <?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['date']='';
 include 'connect.php';
 ?>
 <form>
 Date: <input type='date' name='date'> <br>
 <input type='submit' name='submit'>
 </form>
 <?php
 $date='';
 if(isset($_POST['submit'] ))
 {
 $date=$_POST['date'];
 $_SESSION['date']=$date;
 echo $_SESSION['date'];
 }
 ?>

<?php
echo $_SESSION['date'];
?>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're trying to describe.  What specific line of code isn't doing what you expect it to do?  What did you expect it to do?  Why?  And there's nothing here which interacts with a database in any way, so it's not clear why you expected *that* to happen either.

Comment: You are setting `$_SESSION['date']` to `''` *every time*…!

Comment: actually i have set database  connection and it is also connecting       but i forgot to write here.the main problem is i am unable to get the value of session variable outside the code of submit button neither through get method nor post method.

Comment: You can accept my answer if you like

Comment: ya sure i would efinetly accept ypur answer but how to accept it i cant find the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not `echo` because you haven't set any form method and getting the values by `$_POST`.
By default it will take `GET` as form method.
So you can do two things

1. Set the form method to `POST` like this `<form method="post">` or
2. Use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` like this `$_GET['submit']` and `$_GET['date']`.

Comment: I have tried what you said with both $_GET and $_POST method but      still it is  not displaying anything outside submit button

Comment: Does the connect.php is required? Because I don't see any code related to database. Do you have some more code below what you have posted in your question? @NilanjanaMaiti

Comment: And just to confirm, do you mean the echo at last line of your code as the outside of submit button code? @NilanjanaMaiti

Comment: Ya its echoing after i appiled GET method but when i am trying to echo the $_SESSION[''date] in another page it is not echoing there and it is also not getting to database through insert query

Comment: yes connect.php is there but i forgot to mention the code is given below for connect.php

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
      <head>
 <title>connect</title>

 
</head>
<body>




 <?php
 
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="mydb1";


$mysqli= new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);


?>




</body>
</html>

Comment: As you said you can't get the value of it on another page then it maybe possible that you forget to add `session_start()` at the top of your other page where you are trying to echo date session variable @NilanjanaMaiti

Comment: no prit patel i have added session start .i can show you the code given below:

Comment: <?php  session_start();  echo $_SESSION['date']; ?>

Comment: Can you please post the whole codes of both the pages where you are facing problems. So that i can clearly understand the problem. Because when i copied your code and tried in my PC it works perfectly so there must be an error somewhere else @NilanjanaMaiti

Comment: HEy man its working it was my coding error actually thanks for the help prit patel.thanks very much

Answer (score -1):

The form doesn't have a method.
Set form method to POST